"Be" action or non action verb?
I need to know whether the verb "be" is always considered as a stative verb.
We don't have " I've been being waiting here for 2 hours"
But is it also incorrect to say
" I've been being very patient with my students during all these years"?

Why would it be incorrect? Stative verbs can be used with the progressive aspect in some contexts.

Being seems redundant in your sentence. "I am being patient", but "I have been patient".

Have you ever, as a child, been asked (or even told) "Be quiet!"?  This is special case of the verb, of course, but philosophers the world over debate about whether there are circumstances in which doing nothing (or not doing something) can be a kind of action.

To be rude: He has been being rude to his teachers; we should have a word with him. Answer: Yes, in some cases. Your student one seems ok to me. been being rude, patient, nice etc. are heard more in speech rather than seen in writing.

Afaq: Please respond. Thanks. I worked quite hard on an answer for you and a response from you would be nice.

@Lambie I'm sorry, I've just seen your answer. it explains the matter thoroughly. Thank you for the valuable explanation on the subject

being + adjective (describing a person's state/attitude or thing's state) is often used. These are formed in the following way.

He is being rude to  you.

They are being kind to us.

We are being fair with her.

The organization is being very uncooperative.

I'm being very patient with you.


So, now imagine this you do this with being rude [or being + plus any type of adjective like that]. Phrases like being rude can change see a change in the be main verb in the following way:

He is being rude to you. [right now] present continous
He was being rude to you. [for example: yesterday. past continuous]
He has been being rude to you this past week. [present perfect of be + being rude).
He 'd been being rude to you for weeks when the ruckus erupted.


Callaghan and Hemingway boxed together quite a bit that summer.
Callaghan may have been being generous when he called Hemingway an
amateur. have been being generous
This one, I’d like anyone to win (except the old lady from Two and a
Half Men), but I’ve a soft spot for the ever-amazing Jane Lynch who
has been being funny on TV since forever. Very strong female supporting actresses. British TV show commentator

These are heard in conversation, and are seen less often in writing but in fact may and do occur.
Here is an example from a British publication about education:

In response to Boles’ comments, colleges from the region were eager to
refute claims that they
have been being uncooperative.
FE WEEK

Here is another example, from a linguistics paper, commenting on two sentences "Please hand me the glass or a glass", the author writes:

Furthermore, by the rule of Quantity, the speaker would not have been
being cooperative if they did not believe that there was some way for
the addressee to figure out which glass this is.

.Definiteness and Identification in English
So the verb be is stative: He is being rude. or He has been being rude.  Being + adjective does not change when be as the main verb changes.

You have found a nonce construction, and I believe it an error. There is not a single hit of "been being cooperative" in Google Books: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=been+being+cooperative%2Cbeen+cooperative&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

@LPH: That's why I'm saying you are non-native: He's being uncooperative or cooperative. can both go in the present perfect. What do you not get about the form: being + adjective? There's nothing nonce about it.

Callaghan and Hemingway boxed together quite a bit that summer. Callaghan may have been being generous when he called Hemingway an amateur. being + generous https://www.finebooksmagazine.com/fine-books-news/ernest-hemingway-down-count

Here again, "been being generous" shows not a single hit; the normal fom is "been generous". What more do you say by making this a progressive form? Nothing, I believe. It can be taken as a reclassified progressive, though, and taken to mean "put on a show of generosity"; I'll agree to that, a rare meaning attached to  "be generous" through the progressive. Otherwise what is the use of a progressive that adds nothing?

@LPH All my examples are kosher. being generous does not mean been generous: He is being generous. versus He has been generous. versus He has been being generous with his time. The fact you are even arguing this, shows  you don't know. Ask any other native speaker worth their salt. There are many of them here.

However, you do not explain this new meaning (which should be systematically conferred by this particular use of the progressive, that is with a stative verb or perhaps, just the stative verb "be"); I mean that in all cases it should be deducible according to one  and unique principle; what is that meaning and what is the principle?

@LPH You haven't read my answer. It's the first thing in it. being + adjective.  There is no new meaning. The difference between us is that I admit when I am wrong.

This answer  (II) to a  question closely related to your query does provide the basic principles. In addition, the following section makes explicit that the progressive is not usually acceptable with stative verbs.

A Comprehensive Grammar of the ùenglish Language (Quirk et al.)
§ 4.26 VState, event, and habit with the progressive
The three verb senses of state, event, and habit are differently interpreted
with the progressive:
(a) STATE PROGRESSIVE In many cases […] the progressive is unacceptable with stative verbs:

We own a house in the country.
*We are owning a house in the country.
*Sam's wife was being well-dressed.
This can be explained, in part, by the observation that stative verb meanings
are inimical to the idea that some phenomenon is 'in progress'. States are
'like-parted' in that every segment of a state has the same character as any
other segment: no progress is made. (Contrast We are building a house in the
country.)


In your particular case, no reclassification seems possible (as in the case of "**Mary is being fair haired.*").

The question is about: being plus an adjective. The only way to say that someone is being rude is to say it: He is being rude to his teacher.

@Lambie Not at all, you are talking rubbish! This is no question about adjectives and you have no notion of what is aspect (or pretend  it's not a matter of aspect)!  "He is rude to his wife/lawyer/friends/lady/…" (https://www.google.com/search?q=%22he%20is%20rude%20to%20his%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en - rude to me - being rude to me: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+being+rude+to+me%2Cis+rude+to+me&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3). You should keep the progressive aspect what it is, the aspect of things in progress.

There is an adjective: patient. Look again  at the question. being rude is an expression; He's been being rude to his teacher.

@Lambie "Being rude" is a phrase, and not an idiom, as you seem to insinuate; it needs no more defining than "being sad/disconsolate/merry/agressive/immature/lazy/courageous…".  Is it a new "expression"? It is not found in any dictionariy at the idiom sections. (Not in the Wiktionary (800 000 entries)) In the case of "rude" a reclassification of the meaning seems  possible and the ngram supports this contention, but in the case of "patient" no reclassification makes sense (the ngram shows no hits:  (1/2)

@Lambie https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=has+been+patient%2Chas+been+being+patient&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3 . (2/2)

It doesn't matter what you call it. What matters is that it can be used as in the progressive: to be being stubborn.

@Lambie "Be being patient" is not used, and "be being rude" is found, but very little, which shows the incompatibility of stative verbs with the progressive, and the fact that the meaning is not the usual one..

It gets quite tiring having to explain stuff to someone who simply is not a native speaker. The CGEL thing you quote is irrelevant here. This is not about the progressive with stative verbs. It's about: present perfect of be+ being + adjective.

My answer contains references. And this is not ELU. It's ELL. Your CGEL reference is irrelevant. It does not correspond to the question.  Or as the John Cleese skit says: It is an ex-parrot. It has gone to meet its maker. Others are more generous than I. Good for them. :) [Also, they don't speak French] It's not "be being patient": It's: being patient AND  *have been/being patient/being nice/being sympathetic/being cooperative, etc. etc. etc.
